# How to backup sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, backup

What's the proper way to do it?
Do I just copy the .sq3 file?

What if there are users on the site and file is being written while it's being copied?

Comment: [SQLite has an API for this](http://sqlite.org/backup.html)

Comment: What language and driver are you using to access the database?

Comment: i'm using PHP and the PDO extension

Comment: There is currently a feature request to expose the sqlite backup API in php: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70950

Comment: There is also a [VACUUM INTO](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html#:~:text=The%20VACUUM%20command%20with%20an,I%2FO%20may%20be%20reduced.) command as an alternative to the backup API.

Answer (score 233):

The sqlite3 command line tool features the [`.backup` dot command](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_).

You can connect to your database with:

```
sqlite3 my_database.sq3
```

and run the backup dot command with:

```
.backup backup_file.sq3
```

Instead of the interactive connection to the database, you can also do the backup and close the connection afterwards with

```
sqlite3 my_database.sq3 ".backup 'backup_file.sq3'"
```

Either way the result is a copy named `backup_file.sq3` of the database `my_database.sq3`.

It's different from regularly file copying, because it takes care of any users currently working on the database. There are proper locks set on the database, so the backup is done exclusively.

Comment: You can do it all in one line... `sqlite3 m_database.sq3 ".backup m_database.sq3.bak"`

Comment: @Googie: Can we use it for replication? or

Comment: @mOna: This is just a mechanism for making backups. Replication means propagating changes on the fly (kind of a distributed database), which this won't do for you.

Comment: What does the `.backup` command actually do?  Running `file m_database.sq3.bak` just says that it's an SQLite file.

Comment: @RonJohn It actually makes a copy of a file, but it also ansures, that write access to the database is restricted with proper locks, so it's an atomic operation, no intermediate modifications.

Comment: "file is being written while it's being copied" - In this case, I get `Error: database is locked`

Comment: @RadioControlled As I said earlier - this method locks database to avoid data corruption when there are concurrent users. If other user was first to lock the database (like in your case), then of course backup request will fail, cause it cannot secure a lock.

Comment: So during the backup write operations are blocked?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my assumption is, that only some parts of database are locked at a moment, so only write operations working on these parts will be blocked. Then they will be allowed, once the backup process moves onto other parts of database.

Comment: You should also specify a timeout to minimize `database is locked` errors... `sqlite3 source.db ".timeout 1000" ".backup backup.db"`

Comment: @Melvyn It's correct that the `.timeout` command helps (internally, [it calls](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/bc85a51595d8afb0f82b3723050f0a6faa6082bc/src/shell.c.in#L10170-L10172) [sqlite3_busy_timeout](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html)), however for larger databases the timeout should be way larger than 1000, as that is the time in miliseconds allowed to be accumulated before the command will error out with "database is locked" errors again.

Comment: Is it possible to execute .backup with an SQLiteOpenHelper object in Android? I don't want to use the cumbersome shell command if possible.

Comment: There is no `.backup` command in the SQL of SQLite, as it is a feature of the command line tool. Still, from version 3.27.0 you can use `VACUUM INTO filename;`, as documented here https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html#vacuuminto It will not modify your source database at all.

Comment: Just overwitten the 700GB database file :( confused where the src and dst are

Answer (score 25):

`.backup` is the best way:

```
sqlite3 my_database ".backup my_database.back"
```

you can also try `.dump` command, it gives you the ability to dump the entire database or tables into a text file. If TABLE specified, only dump tables matching LIKE pattern TABLE.

```
sqlite3 my_database .dump > my_database.back
```

A good way to make an archival copy using dump and store, Reconstruct the database at a later time.

```
sqlite3 my_database .dump | gzip -c > my_database.dump.gz
zcat my_database.dump.gz | sqlite3 my_database
```

Also check this question [Do the SQLite3 .backup and .dump commands lock the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744297/do-the-sqlite3-backup-and-dump-commands-lock-the-database)

Comment: On SQLite 3.8.2, `.backup` doesn't work as shown above ("missing FILENAME argument on .backup")

Comment: This is the best answer. If you are using .backup on a working database used by many it may not work because at some point the database is locked.
So if you are using this in a CRON it won't work and won't tell you there is an error... better use .dump (allways works) or the API given by SQLite.

Comment: @Memristor But doesn't .dump lock the DB for others?  FWIW, I would prefer a failed backup (with mail to the admin) to a disrupted service.

Comment: Please fix .backup syntax in your answer. It doesn't need '>' operator

Comment: @Memristor but locks exist for a reason, i.e. to not dump a corrupted database in the middle of a write. Problem is better solved by first issuing a .timeout [ms]; command before .backup; That way .backup will wait for lock to be released up to [ms] milliseconds before failing.

Comment: @JohnyTex for sure, I did say that because I used to work on a project that wrongly chose SQLite... the thing is that while the database was being accessed some new programmer copy-pasted the database because "hey! it's just a file" and that's when the party began :)

Answer (score 5):

For streaming replication of SQLite, check out [Litestream](https://github.com/benbjohnson/litestream).

Compared to using the sqlite3-backup command, this is automatic, and incremental.

If you need to restore from backup, the data will be a lot more up to date than if you did a regular backup every hour for example.

Answer (score 3):

**Short and simple answer would be**

`sqlite3 m_database.sq3 ".backup m_database.sq3.bak"`

Answer (score 1):

People who want to do the backup from within their app should check out the backup API at https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: note: some example usage could improve the long-term value of this post.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form you can run from project root a command of the following form (default format is JSON, other options include XML, YAML, see the links below):

```bash
./manage.py dumpdata --output mydata.json
```

You might want instead to dump only specific django apps in your project, e.g. assuming you created your app with `manage.py startapp dinsdaleapp`:

```bash
./manage.py dumpdata dinsdaleapp --output dinsdaleapp-data.json
```

It's also possible to only dump specific models:

```bash
./manage.py dumpdata dinsdaleapp.institution -o institutions-data.json
```

To restore the previously created dump

```bash
./manage.py loaddata mydata.json
```

To dump flatpages:

```
./manage.py dumpdata flatpages -o flatpages.json
```

In case you prefer a timestamped backup:

```bash
./manage.py dumpdata flatpages -o dumps/flatpages-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S).json
```

For details and options see:

```bash
./manage.py dumpdata --help
./manage.py loaddata --help
```

Also see:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats