# Daily Backups of Django Site Using sqlite

Tags: linux, django, sqlite

I have a small django project using sqlite and I want to set up automated daily backups.

My question is can I simply copy the sqlite file or do I need to pause/lock it during copying to prevent any corruption?

If I do need to do anything special to pause/lock it, what do I need to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to backup sqlite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675314/how-to-backup-sqlite-database)

Comment: Yes, assuming that's the right answer it works for me.