# sqlalchemy+sqlite: backing up db file

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, database-backups

I'm using a sqlite database with sqlalchemy in a python web app. I'd like to periodically back up the database by copying the file to blob storage. Obviously I can just copy the file, but I figure this'll lead to a corrupted backup if a write operation occurs while the file is being copied.

One approach is to acquire a file lock everywhere in my application that writes to the DB. But that's a bit error prone. Any recommendations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675314/how-to-backup-sqlite-database and https://sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: Thanks. The stackoverflow question suggests using the .backup command. However, this command doesn't seem to work through sqlalchemy, only through the sqlite tool. I've tried engine.execute(".backup").

Comment: The second documentation page explains how to do backups with the C-API, which I'm also not sure how to use from python.

Comment: OK, this seems to work: `subprocess.check_call(["sqlite3", running_db_filename, f".backup {target_path}"])`

Comment: If you're satisfied with that approach then consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
subprocess.check_call(["sqlite3", running_db_filename, f".backup {target_path}"])
```

Only downside is vulnerability to injection.