# Wordpress on SQLite: Problems on moving from server to local

Tags: wordpress, sqlite, laragon

i'm trying to move my SQLite Wordpress site from server to local using Laragon, but the site fails to start.

So, I've succefuly created a wordpress site without using MySQL in a remote server, just with the help of a plugin named SQLite Database Integration, made my tests - and it's working (mostly) ok. Small hiccups, but nothing i can't handle.

Now, i needed to transfer my database back to local development, as a backup and a proof that my site is, finally, as portable as ever. The objective goal is to have two or three files downloaded to a local server, and be functional as it was in the remote server.

So, I've installed Laragon, and downloaded all the content of my remore location - all the wordpress core files, the themes, the plugins, and the database file, everything as was in the server. I've changed nothing on the files, but made sure that the SQLite 3 and PDO SQLite are checked on my Laragon's PHP extensions.

Sadly, it doesent work - i get a fatal error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed in C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\class-wp-sqlite-translator.php:379 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\class-wp-sqlite-translator.php(379): PDO->query('CREATE TABLE IF...') #1 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\class-wp-sqlite-db.php(234): WP_SQLite_Translator->__construct(Object(PDO)) #2 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php(773): WP_SQLite_DB->db_connect() #3 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\class-wp-sqlite-db.php(31): wpdb->__construct('', '', '', '') #4 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\db.php(64): WP_SQLite_DB->__construct() #5 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\db.php(37): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #6 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\load.php(666): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #7 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-settings.php(124): require_wp_db() #8 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-config.php(96): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #9 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #10 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #11 C:\laragon\www\test\index.php(17): require('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #12 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\plugins\sqlite-database-integration\wp-includes\sqlite\class-wp-sqlite-translator.php on line 379`

Any ideas on what i'm i doing wrong - and what should be the correct steps to make Wordpress truly portable :)

Comment: why not simply make a normal backup and then restore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675314/how-to-backup-sqlite-database

Comment: i thought/hopped that an FTP copy should do the job. Since i don't use shell commands, this would be a more difficult way for me to work...

Comment: usually you have already a backup strategy where a shell command will do the backup and store it automatically, where you can grab it with sftp.